# Only Show X Amount of Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would one only show a certain amount of divs? Right now I'm using the following code to show only 5 divs.. but it's not working properly:

```
$('.categoryThumbnailList_item:lt(5)').show();
```

I created a JSFiddle to showcase the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/gXxEs/

I don't want the divs to load and be hidden either.  I would like the divs to not appear at all and not have to be loaded on the screen.

Any help would be appreciated! :D

Comment: Is this on an event, or should only `n` divs always be visible? If the latter, you could do this with just CSS.

Comment: I would only like 5 divs to be visible and the read to not be shown and also not load on the page either. If you set the visibility to be hidden for any of the divs past the 5 amount they will still load, but be hidden.  I don't want that... I don't want them to load at all.

Comment: If you don't want them to load at all, do this server side. If you want them to just be invisible, try `display: none;`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gXxEs/29/ - this is the updated jsfiddle that works.

Comment: If you want a css-only solution, check out my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, I ended up using @Sven Bieder's code. One more quick question... I set the display to none on my divs and made it so it only shows 6 of the categorythumbnaillist_item div classes. If I have 500 of those categorythumbnaillist_item divs, that are all hidden (via display:none) will this slow down the loading time of my webpage, or will the hidden divs load at all?

Comment: The entirety of the HTML document is downloaded by the client, hidden elements included.  If the client should not view specific elements ever (ie. there is no toggle for displaying/hiding the content), it should not be included in the HTML.  JS and CSS can only hide/remove elements after they have been downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hide all then show the ones you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.categorythumbnaillist_item').hide();
    $('.categorythumbnaillist_item:lt(5)').show();
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gXxEs/9/

Comment: Awesome man! This works fine. But is there any way to make the hidden divs not load at all? Because if I have hundreds of divs they will all be hidden, but they will also load on page as well.  I don't want that.

Comment: Dont do that with script, which is client side, you need to chose not to load the divs on the server side.

Comment: Well, you could set the style property to `display:none` when you print each `div` element. Then, your original code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set the divs to `display: none;` in your CSS and show them with your exact snippet `$('.categoryThumbnailList_item:lt(5)').show();` on page load?

Take care, your Fiddle has a problem. jsfiddle is automatically wrapping the code in your script block in an onload event (changeable on the left side).

I have updated the fiddle, hope it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/7XneS/2/

**Update:**
If you want to **REMOVE** the divs entirely, you can of course use the jQuery function `.remove()`. If you don't want that the divs appear at all on the page, you have to take care of this on the server side and not put them out.

Comment: @jwatts1980 Thanks you are right. Just used `visibility: hidden` in my current project and got confused by that ;).

Answer (score 0):

You then remove all divs with index greater than 4:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.categorythumbnaillist_item:gt(4)').remove();
});
```

Example [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gXxEs/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a function to do the work

```
function showLimit(selector, count) {
    $(selector).each(function() {
        if (count > 0) {
            $(this).show();
            count--;
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

Or

```
function showLimit(selector, count) {
    $(selector).hide();
    $(selector+':lt('+count+')').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide them with CSS, try something like this (given your selector):

```
.categorythumbnaillist_item {
    display: none;
}

.categorythumbnaillist_item:nth-of-type(-n+5) {
    display: block;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gXxEs/41/).

**Note:**

This only works [if the browser supports CSS3](http://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20selectors).